# Combobox CSS style not applying in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a small problem with my webpage. I have a combobox and I've written a CSS class for it. It works fine except in IE7. Can  anybody give me a solution for that?

This is my CSS:

```
.textbox_short{
   float:left;
   width:150px;
   padding:3px;
   margin-left:10px;
   /*margin-bottom:5px;*/
   margin-top:5px;
   font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
   font-size:12px;
   color:#666;
   border:1px solid #F90;
}
```

And my HTML:

```html
<select name="drop_country" class="textbox_short" id="drop_country">
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

IE<8 does not give padding and border to `SELECT` elements. Try to wrap `SELECT` inside a DIV or `SPAN` Follow this link

[IE6/IE7 css border on select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380037/ie6-ie7-css-border-on-select-element)