# How to disable select box border in IE7

Tags: css, xhtml

I Have tried this

```
select
{
border:0;
}

<select>
<otpion value='male'>Male</option>
<otpion value='female'>Female</option>
</select>
```

its not working in IE6, IE7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question and its answers, here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380037/ie6-ie7-css-border-on-select-element).

(Short answer: It can't be done. There might be complicated workarounds, though.)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible in IE6/7 as the elements in question are controlled by the OS, not the browser.  That's why they look different in Windows compared to Mac. Some browsers let you style them to some degree with straight CSS, but definitely not all.

But fear not, if you're willing to dig into some extra code, you can use something like [this demo](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html). It uses the jQuery UI, which is helpful for many, many other things as well.

Another example would be [this here](http://www.8stream.com/blog/entry/styleselect) and [this one too](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/), along with the popular [jScrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/).

Hope some of that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me, in both FF and IE9:

```
outline:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select boxes, like most form elements are "native objects" in IE. Meaning, the look and feel is largely dictated by the OS. Assuming you remembered to wrap the CSS above in a style tag then if the code doesn't work it probably can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

> select {      filter:
>   progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=-1,
>   OffY=0,color=#525252)
>   progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=1,
>   OffY=0,color=#525252)
>   progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0,
>   OffY=-1,color=#525252)
>   progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0,
>   OffY=1,color=#525252);   }

Comment: You may want to explain your answer for the benefit of the OP