# IE 7, Chrome 10 & Opera 11 don't support css backgrounds for select fields - options?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, opera, css

I am using the simple css code below for a select field & it works in all browsers that I have tested apart from IE7, Chrome 10 & Opera 11.

```
background: url(../images/standard-select-bg.png) no-repeat;
```

What are my options for those browsers?

Comment: I think this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380037/ie6-ie7-css-border-on-select-element Your best option might be a replacing the control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For single item select:

- With `background-color: transparent`, Firefox shows image, Chrome and Opera doesn't.
- With `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)`, all browsers show image.

For multiple item select:

- Opera shows image only when using `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)`, Firefox and Chrome shows in all cases.

Working at least in Opera 11.10beta

Comment: +1, nice work finding a way to do it in Opera! I couldn't make it show in Chrome (11.0.696.3 dev / Windows 7) or IE7 (obviously) with either `background-color` though.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's simply not possible in IE7 or Opera 11.

Choices:

- Forget about the `background-image` in those browsers.

  - Neither has a *massive* amount of market share. It is worth spending extra time on them for a minor cosmetic effect?
- Use JavaScript to replace the `<select>` elements with a "fake version".

  - You can style this however you like.
  - For example, [Emblematiq Niceforms](http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/) or [jqTransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/) or the [Uniform plugin](http://uniformjs.com/).
  - It's quite a lot of extra work.

Unless the `background-images` are *essential*, I'd go with Option #1.

Comment: I just found out it doesn't work in Chrome either. For some reason I missed it before.

Comment: about market share, it depends on where. If you have a global business you might be careful with this assertion. Check gs.statcounter.com in different countries such as eastern Europe for example.

Answer (score 1):

my site is http://arpitk.me.pn/ and it's background images didn't loaded too in chrome but it showed fine on firefox
so i fixed it by using html {length:100%;} in css file and it loaded fine in chrome 
but ie and opera lags it