# Internet Explorer form styling problem in Quirks Mode vs Standards Mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, quirks-mode

I have switched from Quirks Mode to Standards Mode (HTML 4.01 Transitional), and have noticed that in IE7 and IE8 all form elements are now styled differently than they have been in Quirks Mode.

In Quirks Mode the select dropdown boxes did not have borders around the elements and looked kind of sleek, whereas after adding the DOCTYPE declaration, select's are shown with borders both around the input rectangle and around the square with the little black triangle which looks very much like Windows 95.

I am seeing this change in the styling behaviour on Windows 7 systems with the default standard skin with transparency enabled.

Apparently in Quirks Mode the fancy Windows system skin is applied to the styling of forms elements, whereas switching to HTML 4.01 Transitional switches to the classic old-style Windows-95 look. The difference can be seen easily by opening a form in Quirks Mode (i.e. no doctype) in Internet Explorer and then switching the document mode to IE8 Standards via the Developer Tools window (F12).

I don't have any CSS rules defined for form elements such as input's, select's, etc, i.e. this affects the unstyled display of form elements.

My question is: how do I get IE8 to display forms with 'fancy' system skins for pages with a doctype?

I realize that I can do custom form styling with CSS but is there a way to enforce system decorations to be applied to default form elements in Standards Mode? Or am I missing something?

The doctype I am using is `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like certain things like the appearance of dropdown buttons cannot be modified - these are browser/os specific.

Why Internet Explorer uses a generic Window Classic style for pages with a DOCTYPE, and the fancy OS-defined decorations for Quirks Mode remains a mistery.

Answer (score 2):

There's a way to force IE to use a particular rendering engine, with the [X-UA Compatible meta tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It looks like your page will render in Quirks mode if you use something like the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5" >
```

However, I have *no* experience with this, so it might not work at all. :D

Comment: Also, even if this does trigger quirks mode, I have serious doubts as to whether it will render those inputs the way you want. **Edit**: Actually, after trying it quickly in IE9, this may very well work for you. No help for other browsers, of course...

Comment: Hm, thing is I don't want to get back to Quirks mode with its surrogate CSS box model and idiosyncrasies. In fact, that was the reason for switching to Standards Mode. It is only the styling of the select elements that I want to 'migrate' from quirks mode. Not that I personally care about it, but this is the client's requirement.

Comment: @ccpizza Yikes. My answer doesn't really help very much, then... [Here's another question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380037/ie6-ie7-css-border-on-select-element) that kind of deals with it, with a link to [this page](http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect/) that actually says, "Keeping the basic `<select>` is not an option." Good luck.