# Why, on every browsers I checked, the width/height of an input and a select are displayed different?

Tags: html, css

I can't understand why (you can see directly on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Fndd/)), on both input/select box, width/height are different, also if I reset their own properties :

## HTML

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <input class="myInput" />

    <select class="mySelect">
        <option value="">Some</option>
    </select>
    
    <br />
    <br />
    
    <select class="mySelect">
        <option value="">Some</option>
    </select>    
</div>​
```

## CSS

```
​.myDiv
{
    padding:30px;
}

.myInput
{
    border: 1px solid #000000; 
    width: 252px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:20px;
}

.mySelect
{
    border: 1px solid #000000; 
    width: 252px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0; 
    height:20px;    
}
​
```

Why? What I need to reset also?

I know some properties are impossible to define, such as border color or style of the select's button, but at least the size should be the same...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from the [box model](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/). Setting width and height on different elements can have a different interpretation. To solve this, you need to set the `box-sizing` property on these elements. Since it is experimental, you need to prefix it with the browser-specific code to get it to work everywhere.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

If you absolutely need your elements perfectly aligned on some older browser that does not support the above (IE7 does not), you can use javascript to set the sizes. The below script uses a `SELECT` element as the reference size (since its height is fixed on IE7), and uses that to set the size of `INPUT` elements to match. Obviously you would want to add some logic to decide which elements to resize this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
    var width = select.offsetWidth;
    var height = select.offsetHeight;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].style.width = width + 'px';
        inputs[i].style.height = height + 'px';
        inputs[i].style.width = (2 * width - inputs[i].offsetWidth) + 'px';
        inputs[i].style.height = (2 * height - inputs[i].offsetHeight) + 'px';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: But I don't have width/height at 100%, neither padding or margin. I need a solution for this scenario, using "standard" box model...

Comment: @markzzz: What I offered _is_ the solution to your scenario. Even without using percentages, padding or margin, browsers still calculate the sizes of `input` and `select` elements differently. Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tueaK/1/).

Comment: Uhm, I'd like to call it workaround! Yes, it is works, but I can't assert it will "works" on every browsers... (ex IE7-8 it doesnt works...)

Comment: @markzzz: It does work on IE8, though not on IE7. Nevertheless, this is the correct way to deal with the problem on modern browsers. If you must support older browsers, you can use javascript to resize elements. I added an example to my answer, though personally I would not bother with such a kludge.

Comment: The actual problem is that browsers by default apply the `border-box` model to the `select` element. You should reset that to `content-box`. No JS required. http://jsfiddle.net/3Fndd/1/. IE7 is a [different story](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380037/)