# jQuery .css() function not Working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was using the Add class method

```
 $("select[name='" + ABC+ i + "']").addClass('addBorder');
```

This was working in Chrome , FF , safari but not on IE 
So changed it to the .css property ;

```
 $("select[name='" + ABC + i + "']").css({"border-color":"red"});
```

But this is not working either in IE ; Does any one have more suggestions on it ?

Comment: Is there any error you get in IE? When the code runs?

Comment: Try switching your quotes around: `$('select[name="' + ABC + i + '"]')`

Comment: Switching quotes didn't work for me                                       This is the problem for all IE versions                                               I am getting the error on IE as object not supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On older IE you cannot change the border of a `select` element (and, unfortunately, a lot of other things). That's why it seems it doesn't work

As countercheck, `$("select[name='" + ABC+ i + "']").length` should be greater than zero on every browser you're trying  (IE included)

If you have to change border I just suggest to wrap your select into another element and set a border-color to that wrapper.

Comment: .length is returning the Value as 1 , so elements is being fetched , let me try wrapping it around and see what do i get

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you can't apply border to a `<select>` in he, look at this question [IE6/IE7 css border on select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380037/ie6-ie7-css-border-on-select-element)

Comment: Yes that's what I was afraid of.  Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

The select element is the last html element you'll ever want to style with css. I once spent hours trying to customize the select element and got nothing but frustration! Don't do anything to it because very browser has it's own little issues with it. Your client has to live with this fact.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks for the link , I had to use another jQuery tag to check the browser and display the alert window rather than showing the element with red background.