# :Hover pseudo selector not working on Select element in IE

Tags: html, css

i cant seem to make the :hover pseudo selector work on a Select element in IE 7, 8 and 9 even though the documentation that i have found says that IE7+ supports it.

According to this it should be full supported in IE7+:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx#pseudoclasses

Quirksmode says "almost" http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

I have tried using a strict doc type but there is no difference.

Do anybody know a way to make the :hover selector work for the Select element in CSS?

I am just trying to change the border color on :hover, but setting the border doesn't even seem to be supported in IE7. It is supported in IE8+ but :hover is not it seems. Changing the color of the text doesn't even work.

Here is an example (works perfect in both Chrome and FF): http://jsfiddle.net/6VrfW/5/

Comment: You can find the answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380037/ie6-ie7-css-border-on-select-element

Comment: Roko: Thanks, but my question is mainly about the :hover selector. But probably also have to look at a way to fix the border problem for IE7.

Comment: MartinF. NO, you simply cannot. (if you realize how to do it... you're not human. ;) (Humans are too lazy to bother) ) I mean... I have done it before , but I created a JS that replaced my default selects, inputs, radios, checkbxz, all to fit a simple design. On replaced elements you can put Mickey Mouse instead of borders on hover too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `<select>` in a `<div>` and attach the hover to the div.  It's awful, but so is IE.

Comment: Good try. still the text color will not change.

Comment: Roko: It works fine when wrapping the select element (also changing the text color - IE7+ - http://jsfiddle.net/6VrfW/21/). But really hoped that I have missed something so I don't have to change my markup because of browser compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, ended up using this solution, which seems like the only way of making it work for IE8 and IE9.