# How to change border color in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

How to change border color in IE7 ?

I try like this but not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/A4wxX/106/

```
<select name="cmb" style="border:red 2px solid;">
    <option> Option 1 </option>
    <option> Option 2 </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this answer, it's very detailed. Warning, you'll need to know a bit of javascript: [IE6/IE7 css border on select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380037/ie6-ie7-css-border-on-select-element)